# How to remove a parent html element with JS or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unwrap

I have searched and haven't found what I am looking for, what I am trying to do is:

```
<main class="content">
    Content
    <nav class="search">
    </nav>
</main>
```

and at a certain media query change it to

```
<main class="content">
    Content
</main>
<nav class="search">
</nav>
```

is this possible?
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

try [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".search").insertAfter(".content");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="content">
  Content
  <nav class="search">
  </nav>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I try to structure the HTML well enough so that anything relating to media queries is handled in CSS.  I'm not sure what your HTML looks like, but I have learned of the [`window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) method recently, so I think you could use that.

## jQuery

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
  $(".search").insertAfter(".content");
} else {
  $(".search").appendTo(".content");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insertAfter` to remove the element and reinsert after a specific element.

To handle this from a media query, you can use [Modernizr's mq method](https://modernizr.com/docs/#mq). It has better browser support than window.watchMedia(). It supports all browsers that can understand media queries in CSS.

```
   if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 320px)')) {
       $(".search").insertAfter(".content");
   } else {
    //...
   }
```